# join multiple one to many tables group on several id and limit by multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

is this possible in mysql?
join multiple one to many tables group on several id and limit by multiple values

```
    ex.  
    table1
        orderNr productID   eventID packqty orderqty    orderedpk
           1        1           1     20      40            2
           1        2           2     18      18            1
           1        1           1     20      60            3
           2        1           1     20      60            3
           2        3           3     13      39            3
        table2
        eventID productID   barcode
            1       1       1234567890123
            1       1       1234567890124
            1       1       1234567890125
            1       1       1234567890126
            1       1       1234567890127
            1       1       1234567890128
            1       1       1234567890129
            1       1       1234567890130
            1       1       1234567890131
            2       2       1234567890134
            2       2       1234567890135
            2       2       1234567890136
            2       2       1234567890137
            2       2       1234567890138
            3       3       1234567890145
            3       3       1234567890146
            3       3       1234567890147
            3       3       1234567890148
            3       3       1234567890149
the output should look like this
orderNr productID   eventID packqty orderqty    orderedpk
1       1           1       20      100         5
1       1       1234567890123       
1       1       1234567890124       
1       1       1234567890125       
1       1       1234567890126       
1       1       1234567890127       
1       2           2       18      18          1
1       2       1234567890134       
2       1           1       20      60          3
2       1       1234567890128       
2       1       1234567890129       
2       1       1234567890130       
2       3           3       13      39          3
2       3       1234567890145       
2       3       1234567890146
2       3       1234567890147
```

So i need to select the order number group by productID and eventID and limit the shown barcodes with the orderedpk

any help is welcome

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious.
To help us help you generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes nice and pretty data for a question or mock up date and your SQL you tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: i have edited my question...i hope is more readable now

Comment: `SELECT OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty, orderQty, orderedpk
FROM (SELECT OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty, sum(orderqty) as orderQty, sum(orderedpk) as orderedpk, 1 as zorder
      FROM table1 T1
      GROUP BY OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty

      UNION ALL

      SELECT T1.OrderNr, T2.ProductID, T2.EventID, Null, Null, Null, 2 as zOrder
      FROM table2 t2
      INNER JOIn table1 T1
         on t1.productID = t2.productID
        and t1.eventID = t2.eventID
      ORDER BY orderNr, ProductID, zOrder, EventID) SubQ`

Comment: SELECT OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty, orderQty, orderedpk 
FROM (SELECT OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty, sum(orderqty) as orderQty, sum(orderedpk) as orderedpk, 1 as zorder 
FROM wcf1_customerorder T1 where T1.orderNr = 1 GROUP BY OrderNr, ProductID, EventID, packqty 
UNION ALL SELECT T1.OrderNr, T2.ProductID, T2.EventID, Null, Null, Null, 2 as zOrder 
FROM wcf1_barcodes T2 
INNER JOIn wcf1_customerorder T1 on T1.productID = T2.productID and T1.eventID = T2.eventID and orderNr = 1
ORDER BY orderNr, ProductID, zOrder, EventID) SubQ

Comment: Hi there. Tried your query it's looking good but it's not applying the limit on the number of barcodes to show. I have to show from the table2 only the number of barcodes from orderedpk. I have edited a little bit your query but still not making the limit

Comment: Was testing using a simulated row_number via user variables and ran into this: User 'rextester_user' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 10000) http://rextester.com/VXYH73357  It's not presently working.

Comment: Hi there...this is working but without the limit. http://rextester.com/PVO42230

Comment: Been trying keep getting: Error occurred (Service Unavailable). Try again later.